# Partial ffill in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with the status in there. There is a period where a status is undetected, because there is either a waiting period or a data gap. I would like to replace this with "waiting time after A". However, there is a lot more undefined values and I only want to change the values after change 1 and before "B".

Is there a way to ONLY fill the values after change 1 which stops when status "B" is reached?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "Status": [A, A, A, A, A, change 1, undetected, undetected, undetected, undetected, undetected, B, B, B, B, B, change 2, undetected, undetected, undetected]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Expected output:

```
"Output": [A, A, A, A, A, change 1, waiting time after A, waiting time after A, waiting time after A, waiting time after A, waiting time after A, B, B, B, B, B, change 2, undetected, undetected, undetected]
```

I have used the ffill function, but then all "undetected" status will be changed with the previous version, which is not the intention in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tricky, and this may not work if you have edge cases, but working within the params you have given,

import pandas as pd

```
data = {
  "Status": ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'change 1', 'undetected', 'undetected', 'undetected', 'undetected', 'undetected', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'change 2', 'undetected', 'undetected', 'undetected']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

```
change_1 = df['Status'].eq('change 1')
status_b = df['Status'].eq('B')


df.loc[((change_1 | status_b).cumsum().eq(1)) & df['Status'].eq('undetected'),
                                               'Status'] = 'waiting time after A'



print(df)

                  Status
0                      A
1                      A
2                      A
3                      A
4                      A
5               change 1
6   waiting time after A
7   waiting time after A
8   waiting time after A
9   waiting time after A
10  waiting time after A
11                     B
12                     B
13                     B
14                     B
15                     B
16              change 2
17            undetected
18            undetected
19            undetected
```